# Multiple Rows in a DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, datagridview

is there a possibility of entering a new line of a Text in a DataGridViewCell by pressing enter?
I have tried the method with the `DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` and the `AutoSizeRowsMode`. The problem with that is, that the row is only resizing when the focus is leaving the cell. And the next line can only be opened with shift-enter.